# Daisy chaining power through mcu modules

Tags: power, pic

I am really sorry if the following question is too obvious and basic, I am trying to understand how I can do this right.

I have five 5V PIC custom modules that I am trying to power, using a daisy chain. These are just PWM generators with a few LED indications. The current draw of each module is about 30mA. So my total current consumption is around 150mA.

I have a 12V to [5V, 3A converter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00J3MHRNO) as my power source and is daisy chained to power these modules.

The problem I am facing is that every time I power this system, one module resets unexpectedly after some time. But when I power it and test it individually then it works fine. I also placed another module in that position and it behaves the same way. So I assume that it is resetting due to brown out reset whenever the voltage drops below 2.7V.

**If this is true, why is my voltage dropping below 5V in this daisy chain?
Is it because of branching?**

The wires I am using for daisy chain are solid AWG 20 wires. I have soldered these wires to 5 screw terminals on a prototype board. The PIC modules don't have decoupling capacitors between its Vdd and Vss, I am suspecting that this might too is affecting the operation. PIC used is PIC16f18344.

I tried searching online for techniques for implementing daisy chain and related design considerations, but had no luck.

Please advise what I must be missing here and/or if I did not consider some requirements.

I have shown a simple connection diagram of all the blocks involved. Please excuse how the diagram is extremely basic and confusing. The green small boxes are the screw terminals. and the black wires are just indicating how the positive and negative lines are running from the source. 
[image]

Comment: what kind of bypass caps are you using to isolate noise on the line?

Comment: @dandavis I am not using any bypass capacitors. Is that why this is acting unexpectedly because of no bypass capacitors? I assumed that the 12V to 5V converter would provide constant filtered  5V voltage

Comment: try adding some to each MCU's input. I really like 10uf ceramics, easy, cheap, no polarity, plenty of capacity (generally).

Comment: @dandavis Thank you for your comment! But is that it? Is there no other design consideration to take into account when using a daisy chain?

Comment: no, not really. you can try the caps in the terminal blocks to see if they help. you have them all wired in parallel, which is quite typical. you might put a spare big cap on the "main" 5v power branch, maybe 330-3300uf @10v+. even if not ideal, caps vs no caps matters hugely.